# Only show content of 1 array by it's name

Tags: php, arrays

If have and array like this:

```
Array ( 
[Example1] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => 
    ) 
[Example2] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => 
        [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => 
        [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => 
        [15] => [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => 
        [20] => [21] => [22] => [23] => [24] => 
        [25] => [26] => [27] => [28] => [29] => 
        [30] => [31] => [32] => [33] => [34] => 
        [35] => [36] => [37] => [38] => [39] => 
        [40] => [41] => [42] => [43] => [44] => 
        [45] => [46] => [47] => [48] => [49] => 
        [50] => [51] => [52] => [53] => [54] => 
        [55] => [56] => [57] => [58] => [59] => 
        [60] => [61] => [62] => [63] => [64] => 
        [65] => [66] => [67] => [68] => [69] => 
        [70] => [71] => [72] => [73] => [74] => 
        [75] => [76] => [77] => [78] => [79] => 
        [80] => [81] => [82] => [83] => [84] => 
        [85] => [86] => [87] => [88] => [89] => 
        [90] => [91] => [92] => [93] => [94] => 
        [95] => [96] => [97] => [98] => [99] => 
        [100] => [101] => [102] => [103] => [104] => 
        [105] => [106] => [107] => [108] => [109] => 
        [110] => [111] => [112] => [113] => [114] => 
        [115] => [116] => [117] => [118] => [119] => 
        [120] => [121] => [122] => [123] => [124] => 
        [125] => [126] => [127] => [128] => [129] => 
        [130] => [131] => [132] => [133] => [134] => 
    ) 
)
```

There's is 2 primary arrays (Example1 & Example2) and in those another array is made. I would like to know how I can only call only 1 array like "Example2" so it print only that one and ignore "Example1"

Please note that there could be more than 2 primary arrays.

And what if with that array I want to build a drop down menu, here what I have:

```
$__selectGroups = '';
    foreach ($groups as $key => $options)
    {
        sort($options);
        if ($key !== '')
        {
            $__selectGroups .= '<optgroup label="'.$key.'">';
        }
        $__selectGroups .= implode("\n", $options);
        if ($key !== '')
        {
            $__selectGroups .= '</optgroup>';
        }
    }
```

How can I tell to build the drop down with only Example2 and ignore the others?

Comment: Maybe you could `print_r()` that so it is more readable and not on one line?  Thanks.

Comment: `print_r($array['Example2'])`?

Comment: Yeah I know, I just want to build a drop down menu with the array I choose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question... seems too simple:

```
print_r($yourArray['Example1']);
```

Since you edited your question, I think you want to do this?

```
foreach ($yourArray['Example1'] as $key => $value) {
}
```

This paradigm for accessing nested arrays applies across the board...

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($yourArray['Example1']);
print_r($yourArray['Example2']);
echo '<pre>';
```

Or you need something more elaborated?